# cxf inbound and outbound message logging to the separate log file

Tags: logging, log4j, cxf, slf4j

I looked up all messages but did not find a clear answer for that question.

How can I configure logging to log CXF inbound and outbound restful messages ?

I have the following setup.

- File org.apache.cxf.Logger with

  ```
  org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
  ```
- applicationContext.xml has the following (it sounds silly, but it is the only place for interceptors I could get messages output)

  ```
  <bean id="abstractLoggingInterceptor" abstract="true">
  <property name="prettyLogging" value="true"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"
  parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"/>
  <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"
  parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor"/>

  <cxf:bus>
  <cxf:inInterceptors>
  <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:inInterceptors>
  <cxf:outInterceptors>
  <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:outInterceptors>
  <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
  <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
  <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
  <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
  </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
  </cxf:bus>
  ```

I tried to follow these instructions with slf4j and with log4j, but the the only output I get to the file is application log messages. I can see inbound and outbound messages on my console.

Can I get something similar to logback.xml work for me, so I separate app logs and message logs. Example: http://www.wolfe.id.au/2011/05/20/apache-cxf-logging/

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
I removed  org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger from my classpath, and placed the following to my log4j.xml. It logging to the file and to console when the level of logging is equal to INFO.

```
<appender name="RSLOGFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="file" value="${project.basedir}/logs/cxf_inout_messages.log"/>
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="100KB"/>
<!-- Keep one backup file -->
<param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<!-- Print the date in ISO 8601 format -->
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>
<logger name="org.apache.cxf">
<level value="ERROR"/>
<appender-ref ref="RSLOGFILE"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you are using CXF 2.2.8 or higher, you would need to do the following:

**step 1)** Create a file `META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` on the classpath containing the following:

```
org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger
```

If you're using Maven, this new file must be in `src/main/resources/META-INF/cxf`, not below `src/main/webapp`!

**step 2)** If you want to log all messages, create a CXF `LoggingFeature`, set the `prettyLogging` property to `true` and add it to the CXF bus.

**step 3)** Add the needed jar files for log4j and slf4j-log4j12. If you are using Maven, include following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**step 4)** In you `log4j.xml` set the log level of `org.apache.cxf.services` to INFO, set `additivity` to `FALSE` and attach a dedicated appender:

```
<!-- level INFO needed to log SOAP messages -->
<logger name="org.apache.cxf.services" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <!-- specify a dedicated appender for the SOAP messages -->
    <appender-ref ref="WS_LOG_FILE" /> 
</logger>
```

I've created a [blog post which explains how to configure CXF for log4j in more detail](https://www.codenotfound.com/2015/01/jaxws-cxf-logging-request-response-soap-messages-log4j.html).

Comment: Everything here is fine, just a little note:

Remember to put "META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger" under for example src/main/resources instead of "src/main/webapp" as I did. That way it will be under classpath.