# CXF LoggingFeature doesn't log inbound request

Tags: java, logging, cxf, log4j2, slf4j

I've upgraded the cxf version in my application from 2.x to 3.3.2 and therefore want to replace the now deprecated `LoggingInInterceptor` and `LoggingOutInterceptor` I've used before with the `LoggingFeature`. For that I've removed the interceptor beans from the cxf bus and added the `LoggingFeature` instead, like this:

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingFeature">
             <property name="prettyLogging" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

I've already had the other steps to use the cxf `LoggingFeature` with my slf4j setup [as described in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424058/cxf-inbound-and-outbound-message-logging-to-the-separate-log-file) added beforehand to use with the interceptors: The `META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` file and the `org.apache.cxf` log4j2 logger.

Now the result is that incoming requests (should be the cxf logging type `REQ_IN` imo) are not logged, but the responses (`RESP_OUT`) are.

What could cause such an behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

For history.
I have the same problem.
You need to change the logging level, because by default this feature logging only if the logging level is "INFO'.

I did the next and it works for me:

```
<bean id="eventSender" class="org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.slf4j.Slf4jVerboseEventSender">
    <property name="loggingLevel" value="WARN" />
</bean>
```

I found it here [Log soap request and response using apache-cxf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906371/log-soap-request-and-response-using-apache-cxf)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone stumbles upon such an error: The interceptor chain was interrupted in my application before it reached the LoggingInterceptor, therefore the incoming request was not logged.